# Jenkins jira-plugin dsl implementation

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-plugin, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm currently trying to implement a release step in jenkins and jira where I want to tag released issues with a fix version, release the version and then post the release notes to somewhere.

Our whole pipeline is done with job DSL and not pipeline. I have found jira-plugin which i think might be able to to this but I can't figure out how to set it up?

For example, how should this be used? https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.jiraIssueUpdater - I find the documentation really bad.

I think I want something like below (with other steps in between ofc), does it make sense?

```
wrappers {
    generateJiraReleaseNotes {
        environmentVariable('JiraReleaseNotes')
        projectKey(${PROJECT_KEY})
        release(${VERSION})
        filter('status in (To be released)')
    }
}
step {
    extractJiraEnvironmentVariables()
}
publishers {
    createJiraVersion {
        projectKey(${PROJECT_KEY})
        version(${VERSION})
    }
    jiraIssueUpdater() //update everything with status "to_be_released" to the createdJiraVersion
    releaseJiraVersion {
        projectKey(${PROJECT_KEY})
        release(${VERSION})
    }
```

also... How do I set up credentials for this plugin? I would like to do it per code and not in the manage jenkins tab.